# What is happening when I assign two Dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am noticing some interesting behavior in my code.

If I do df1=df2, and then df2=df3. Why does df1 also equal df3, if I look inside? Something to do with DataFrame.copy(deep=True)?

Would the same behavior be observed in simple variables, or only complex objects like DFs?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: All variable assignments work like this in Python. Please read Ned Batchelder's [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No, they don't: with `df2=1; df3=2; df1=df2; df2=df3`, then `df1 == 3` while `df2 == 4 and df3 == 4`. Same goes for e.g. lists as well. Show an example of the assignments you mean.

Comment: @Evert Oh, you are right. I read the question too quickly.

Comment: "Something to do with DataFrame.copy(deep=True)?": yes. The variable names just point to the actual object in memory, and to keep things "cheap" (avoid copying unless asked), the dataframes contents (memory) are not automatically copied. And indeed, this happens normally for complex (large) objects.

Comment: Can you post an actual example, @MishaAM ?

Comment: Actually, in my experience, your claim is not true. My `df1` is different from `df2` and `df3`. Hence I'll echo juanpa.arrivillaga's question: please post some self-contained example that produces this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, I added a picture from my Notebook that shows this.

Comment: Don't use pictures: copy-paste the actual input and output.

Comment: Where is the third dataframe in your example code? Your example code and your question are different. The answer to what's happening in the example code (not in your question) is essentially in the comments.

Comment: df3, is just an altered df1. It is just to illustrate that after changing df1, df2 also changes, even though the the assignment of df2=df2 happened prior to df changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to copy values instead of the memory location, you need to use df1 = df2.copy(). This is true mostly for complex objects.